# Swiip/generator-gulp-angular remove components folder

Tags: angularjs, gulp, yeoman-generator

I have used [Swiip](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) to scaffold app.Now I am trying to customize it. There are lots of unnecessary folders under src folder like components and I want to remove components folder.But there is no success.My console shows error

(index):62 GET http://localhost:3000/app/components/navbar/navbar.directive.js

(index):63 GET http://localhost:3000/app/components/githubContributor/githubContributor.service.js

I tried to find where is dependency of these files but no success.
As well if I comment everything then there is no error it means from somewhere these two files are getting called.

Comment: My bad have to run command gulp and then gulp serve and it got fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiip has an architecture and you should understand it for nice programming performance.

The folder Component should containe your features for example (navbar, customers, suppliers, ...) all your modules should be as a folder under component and each folder should containe all the files concerning this module(controller, html, service, directive) if you do so you won't need to reference your files it does it itself.

I hope that my answear helped you ... at all I can help anyTime